# incorporeal, corporeal source in case of spells and damage

Tags: pathfinder-1e

In the *incorporeal* description it is said "*... Even when hit by spells or magic weapons, it takes only half damage from a corporeal source...*"

What is/isn't a corporeal source?

Do for ex. fireball, call lightning, cone of cold, lightning bolt and generally spells with an energy descriptor, half or full damage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are all corporeal sources and would only do half damage.  Any weapon, spell or other source of damage from a corporeal creature would be treated as corporeal based damage and subject to half damage rules.  There are a couple of exceptions.  A [Ghost Touch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/ghost-touch) modified weapon is an example of a non-corporeal damage source.

> A ghost touch weapon deals damage normally against incorporeal
>   creatures, regardless of its bonus.

Also, any creature with an [Incorporeal](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Incorporeal) condition (whether temporary or permanent) or the [Incorporeal Monster SubType](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Incorporeal-Ex-) would be another good example.

> Creatures with the incorporeal condition do not have a physical body. 
>   It can be harmed only by other incorporeal creatures, magic weapons or
>   creatures that strike as magic weapons, and spells, spell-like
>   abilities, or supernatural abilities. It is immune to all nonmagical
>   attack forms. Even when hit by spells or magic weapons, it takes only
>   half damage from a corporeal source (except for channel energy).

Comment: Someone may consider for ex. the lightnings generated from a *lightning storm* comes from the sky and not from a corporeal source...

Comment: The sky is still corporeal.  It is part of the physical world, not the spiritual world.